# why netty can not receive many concurrent connection creation(8000+ conns, not one by one)?

Tags: java, c, nginx, netty

Why netty-3.2.5 can not receive many concurrent connection creation(8000+ conns, not one by one), it will throw time-out error, but libevent and nginx which are written by C is OK.
I use NIOSocketFactory, and write a client by C to use multi-processes to simulate many connections.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is os parameter limit on linux. net.core.somaxconn, but c is good than java when setting same value.